# How to select an item from ComboBox using WinAppDriver?

Tags: c#, appium, winappdriver

Generally for web application if we want to select an option from drown we use SelectElement method.

But in Windows application, when I tried to use SelectElement method, I got a below error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been select but was ControlType.ComboBox

So for windows application, How to select a item from ComboBox dropdown ?

Comment: Thanks for updating question good sir!

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to select the items in Combobox dropdown:

1. By Using Keyboard keys if elements don't have unique attribute and value:

   ```
   WindowsElement comboBoxElement = session.FindElementByClassName("ComboBox");
   comboBoxElement.Click();
   comboBoxElement.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
   comboBoxElement.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
   ```
2. By using drop down list Element if it has unique attribute and value:

   ```
   WindowsElement comboBoxElement = session.FindElementByClassName("ComboBox");
   comboBoxElement.Click();
   comboBoxElement.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Light Dismiss").Click();
   ```

Comment: Using SendKey is not elegant way, cause you have to remember where you are in the combobox list, but it's works.

Answer (score 3):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// select an item from a combobox 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">the combo box element</param>
    /// <param name="index">the index of the item in the combobox list</param>
    public void SelectComboboxItem(AppiumWebElement element,int index)
    {
        element.Click();

        var comboBoxItems = element.FindElementsByClassName("ListBoxItem");

        new Actions(element.WrappedDriver).MoveToElement(comboBoxItems[index]).Click().Perform();
        
    }
```

Comment: Can't tell you how many solutions I have worked through until I tried this. It worked a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You can use also combobox item name itself on SendKeys:

```
WindowsElement comboBoxElement = session.FindElementByClassName("ComboBox");
comboBoxElement.SendKeys("combobox item name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
comboBoxElement.FindElement(By.Name("Item Text To Select")).Click();
```

Somehow I could not get success using any of the above suggested items.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by selecting the ComboBox and then sending it the first character of an item in the dropdown list I could reliably select the list item I wanted (but all my list items started with a different first character)

I had 2 ComboBoxes on by form. Here's the code (just 1 line)
First ComboBox the items is the dropdown list were "Pairs" & "Individuals"

driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Cb_Class").SendKeys("P");

2nd Combobox items were "Match Points" and "XIMPs"

driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Cb_ScoringMethod").SendKeys("M");